# CURL: Failed to connect to localhost port 9999: Connection refused

Tags: curl

I'm trying this command

```
curl -X POST --data-binary "uri=http://data.nobelprize.org/dump.nt" http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql
```

however it's enable to connect to localhost port 9999, i see this answer ([curl Failed to connect to localhost port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952676/curl-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80)) but i dont know how to solve that..

Comment: You can try solving it the same way as the other post suggested, by having `--ipv4` (since curl will try to search for the ipv6 address linked to localhost. You can also try to use `127.0.0.1` instead

Comment: you suggest me to try this command like this : curl -X --ipv4 POST --data-binary "uri=http://data.nobelprize.org/dump.nt" http://localhost:9999/bigdata/sparql  ??

Comment: Yes that could be an option.

Comment: in this case , it gives me this error  curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9999: Connection refused