# django 'python manage.py runserver' does not open port in Ubuntu

Tags: python, django, django-2.1

Starting up with Django. On Ubuntu 16.04, using python3.6. On a venv started a project and running the command to start webserver. Here is the output

```
$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 03, 2019 - 14:06:57
Django version 2.1.4, using settings 'tictactoe.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

when I try to access the localhost. I get a connection refused error

```
$ curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000 failed: Connection refused
* Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection     
refused
```

Found that the server isn't listening on port 8000 . Verified with `netstat -an`

Tried with different ports also with `python manage.py runserver 0:8000` Didn't help.

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952676/curl-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80 ?

Comment: @OjasKale I don't think it is a curl issue. The port itself is not listening in the server and I suppose python webserver is not opening the port

Comment: please try "python manage.py runserver 8000"

Comment: So I create a django project under virtualenv with django==2.1.3 and using python==3.5.2 and ran the server and used "curl -v localhost:8000". Inspired by answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/903404/curl-fails-to-connect-to-locahost

Comment: @ShubhamPaliwal Tried it. No luck.

Comment: Also using the "sudo netstat -plnt" verified that 127.0.0.1:8000 has STATE LISTEN

Comment: @AmanRaparia It is not curl error. Even it fails to open in browser .

Comment: Can please try to open the port 8000 on your machine to accept the tcp with ufw and iptables and then again try "python manage.py runserver". Think that in the ufw deny http might be set up

Comment: what I tried to re-create your error and succed with command "sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8000 -j DROP
" and this lead to the same error. I resolved it using the command "sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 8000 -j ACCEPT"

Comment: sorry it did not help

Comment: I did re-provision the vm with Ubuntu 18.04. Its a vanilla server and still I face the issue.