# Linux Azure VM inbound port rule not working

Tags: azure, redhat, azure-vm

I installed Redhat azure VM and I enabled ports 80 and 443. But the ports are not working. I don't know what is the reason. Please anyone help regarding this issue.

Comment: [Troubleshoot Azure VM connectivity problems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-vm-connectivity), [Azure linux VM inbound rules not working for custom port](https://serverfault.com/questions/829358/azure-linux-vm-inbound-rules-not-working-for-custom-port) and [Azure inbound TCP port rules don't work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/513619/azure-inbound-tcp-port-rules-don39t-work-with-mino.html)

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I am searching like this "curl localhost" and get this error "curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused". if I am searching in chrome I get this error "This site can’t be reached12.36.25.254 refused to connect."

Comment: @DeepDave-MT that solution was not workout for me

Comment: [Curl : connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41027340/curl-connection-refused), [curl Failed to connect to localhost port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952676/curl-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80) and [curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 Connection refused](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1215928/curl-7-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-8080-connection-refused)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT Thank you. The above solution also not workout

Comment: in azure redhat machines ill get this iisues

Answer (score 0):

The Error you are getting is more related to require some configurational changes in your local host file.

Solution : You need to add `--IPV4` flag option to `curl` and another things is removing `::1 from /etc/hosts`.

For more information and troubleshooting refer this [***thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22952676/curl-failed-to-connect-to-localhost-port-80)